# Is there a faster npm package than the official eslint-watch?

Tags: javascript, npm, eslint

I'm having slow issues with eslint-watch.
I have tried to optimized with rules, paths, and extenders but with no real luck.

it takes more than **70** seconds to eslint-watch to print to console the issues (or no issues)

I'm running this script on a corporate project:

```
esw --watch --color ./src/
```

src folder size is 2.77 MB with 875 Files

include only JS files (style folder is in src but was ignored in the .eslintignore file

There are no issues with Memory or CPU.

Does anyone have a suggestion? or maybe a better package?

Comment: Does watch mention if it's using polling vs native drivers?

Comment: What do you mean? are you asking what kind of parser am I using? if you do, than babel-eslint.
but I think I didn't understand your question...

Comment: There are two main ways to watch for changes on the file system: Setting a delay and asking the system what is there and then checking that for changes, **or** hooking into a change alert system and having the system tell you what changes happened. The second is faster, but requires special libraries and drivers to work. Usually the log messages will tell you what method is being used.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner, eslint-watch use chokidar package that uses native drivers, there is an option to use polling.
Not sure I understand from your second comment which one is polling and which one is the native drivers

Comment: First is polling. Polling is generally slower.